# How do I prevent the other James from impersonating me in chat?

Tags: support, chat, notifications

Every now and then, I receive notifications of replies to [James](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/4375/james)'s chat messages in the Bridge. [Example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8436848?noredirect=1#8436848). This seems to happen more often when I just engaged in a conversation in chat not very long ago. I will keep receiving notifications not meant for my eyes for a week or so, then it stops.

I don't want to receive replies that are not meant for me. So how do I prevent him from impersonating me? (Or it could just be a bug, if so, how do I get around it?).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if it is a bug. If I'm reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74950/150097 right, `@James` should ping James only, but I'm not sure, since both of you have the same word boundary ending after "James"

Comment: Replies ping only the "real" james, but @james will ping anyone who's name starts with "james" if they've been in the room recently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to truly and permanently get around it would be to change your name.

A quick glance at the chat.SE users list reveals a number of `@Jim *` and `@Jimmy *`'s, so those don't help...

If you didn't mind changing your Chat.SE username to `@Jiao`, that would solve things for you.

As for the *reason* it happens only after you jump into chat, you'll only receive chat pings from rooms in which you've been present recently. So, whenever you come into chat, any pings typed out to `@James` will be sent to your attention for a few days.

Comment: Hmm. so how do I change my display name? My account is linked to my Google account, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @JamesJiao So, Step 1: If you don't want to change your username on any SE sites you're currently an active user of, you should create a new/associate an account at an SE you don't care about. From that SE, go to your profile, and use the edit link at the top to change your username. Then, on chat.se, go to your user page and change your chat.se accounts parent user.

Comment: I don't mind changing my username on all the SE sites. What would be the steps in this case?

Comment: @JamesJiao The same, just skip the first and last steps.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I was going crazy trying to find the edit button on my profile, then I realized the meta site didn't have an edit button. Thanks for the help.